# Cubic Spline Interpolation

Tags: c#

Code from: https://gist.github.com/dreikanter/3526685

Hi,

I got some doubt on the cubic spline interpolation code(C#) from the website that I post.

```
        if (n > 2)
        {
            var sub = new double[n - 1];
            var diag = new double[n - 1];
            var sup = new double[n - 1];

            for (int i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++)
            {
                diag[i] = (_h[i] + _h[i + 1]) / 3;
                sup[i] = _h[i + 1] / 6;
                sub[i] = _h[i] / 6;
                _a[i] = (_values[i + 1] - _values[i]) / _h[i + 1] - (_values[i] - _values[i - 1]) / _h[i];
            }
```

Can anyone explain why the `diag` need to divide by 3? and `superdiagonal` need to divide by 6. And also the `_a` variables formula. I cant understand the code, can someone help to explain why and where the formula come from? I have already make the study and not able to get it.

And next is about the public double GetValue(double key) this method.

```
return ((-_a[gap - 1] / 6 * (x2 + _h[gap]) * x1 + _values[gap - 1]) * x2 +
                (-_a[gap] / 6 * (x1 + _h[gap]) * x2 + _values[gap]) * x1) / _h[gap];
```

I cant understand this part also. Can someone help me for this ?

I would appreciate for those who helping on it.

Thanks very much.

Comment: It's a formula that comes from mathematical derivation of some basic asumption about what a spline should be. First, you should tell us what's your study level in mathematics / calculus so we can adapt the explanation. Second, it's actually not a question specific to programmers, so it might be closed as off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can get basic information here https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Spline_(mathematics) . Best would be a numerical analysis book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about mathematics.